# Make WebView's list scrollable

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, scrollview

I have a page which looks like this*:

```
<ScrollView>
  <WebView/>
  <WebView/>
  <WebView/>
</Scrollview>
```

* not the actual layout, but that it enough for the question and makes the problem clearer.

I don't know how exactly a `WebView` looks like because it can be very variable. A `WebView` *can* contain a scrollable list.

I want to achieve this scrolling behaviour:

[image]

These are two WebViews (the one with the blue header and the one with the green header). I only want to scroll the list in the blue `WebView` when I'm dragging in the list. If I touch anywhere else (for example on the blue or green header), I want to scroll in the `ScrollView`.

My attempt to solve this is a `CustomRenderer` for the `WebView`, which I found in [this thread in the Xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54365/android-enabling-scrolling-for-a-webview-inside-a-scrollview):

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.OldElement != null)
    {
        Control.Touch -= Control_Touch;
    }

    if (e.NewElement != null)
    {
        Control.Touch += Control_Touch;
    }
}

void Control_Touch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    // Executing this will prevent the Scrolling to be intercepted by parent views
    switch (e.Event.Action)
    {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:
            Control.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Up:
            Control.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
    }
    // Calling this will allow the scrolling event to be executed in the WebView
    Control.OnTouchEvent(e.Event);
}
```

This nearly does the job, I can scroll in the list inside of the `WebView` now, but it won't scroll in the `ScrollView` anymore if I tap anywhere else in the `WebView`.

So I tried to check for the height of the inner list:

```
case MotionEventActions.Down:
    if (ComputeVerticalScrollRange() > MeasuredHeight)
        Control.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    break;
case MotionEventActions.Up:
    if (ComputeVerticalScrollRange() > MeasuredHeight)
        Control.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    break;
```

`MeasuredHeight` is the height of the `WebView`. `ComputeVerticalScrollRange()` will always return the same height as `MeasuredHeight` tho. So one possible solution would be to get the height of the inner list in the `WebView`, but I don't know how I can get that (I'm new to Android). And maybe, there are even other solutions to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code `Control.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);`, you will need to make sure this `Control.Parent` is really the `ScrollViewer`.

AFAIK, to implement the view for each platform, it uses renderers, the `Control.Parent` here is the `WebViewRenderer`, so I think what you need is possible this:

```
Control.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

The real problem is when to set it to true or false, you may for example modify your `Control_Touch` event like this:

```
private void Control_Touch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    var viewheight = Control.MeasuredHeight;
    var height = (int)Math.Floor(Control.ContentHeight * Control.Scale);
    switch (e.Event.Action)
    {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:
            downY = e.Event.GetY();
            mAction = ActionState.None;
            Control.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;

        case MotionEventActions.Move:
            upY = e.Event.GetY();
            var delta = downY - upY;
            if (Math.Abs(delta) > MIN_DISTANCE)
            {
                if (delta < 0)
                {
                    mAction = ActionState.TB;
                    //top reached
                    if (Control.ScrollY == 0)
                    {
                        Control.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    }
                }
                else if (delta > 0)
                {
                    mAction = ActionState.BT;

                    //bottom reached
                    if (Control.ScrollY + viewheight + 5 >= height)
                    {
                        Control.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case MotionEventActions.Up:
            Control.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;
    }
    Control.OnTouchEvent(e.Event);
}
```

I used two custom `WebView` to test my demo, the idea is to disable scrolling of `WebView` when it reached top and it is been scrolling from top to bottom, or vice versa. You may have a try.

Comment: I doubted anyone will understand what I'm trying to achieve, but that it exactly what I wanted and it works! Thanks a lot. Only one last thing, Control.Scale is deprecated. Any idea what one should use instead?

Comment: @DennisSchröer, you can try to replace it with `Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density`.

Comment: Found a bug in this. When I scrollced down, `Control.ScrollY` is always 0 if I try to scroll agian until I reached bottom once. So I can only scroll down until I reached the bottom, then I can scroll up again (same behaviour for scrolling up: I can't scroll down again).

Comment: @DennisSchröer, sorry, didn't get it. When scrolling and in the meanwhile it reaches bottom or top, the scrollview should handle the scroll gesture, not the `WebView`.

Comment: Yes, that works as expected. But if I scroll down, `Control.ScrollY` will always be 0. If I then stop the scroll and try to scroll up, if goes into the top if condition (delta < 0). `Control.ScrollY` will still be 0, so the `ScrollView` will handle the scroll gesture.

Comment: @DennisSchröer, yes, because `Control.ScrollY` changes as result of `Scroll listener`, if you've reached bottom and still scroll up, this listener won't be fired, so will it keeps 0.

Comment: I didn't reach the bottom tho. If I scroll a pixel to the bottom, `Control.ScrollY` is always 0. Doesn't matter how far I scroll, it's always 0. Is this expected behaviour?